# Rectifying a Waveform (array of numbers) for Average,RMS and no. of zero crossings c++

Tags: c++, arrays, waveform

I have 3 arrays of numbers from three different waveforms.

I need to rectify each waveform (so the negative values change to their positive equivalent) and find the Average, RMS and number of zero crossings for each waveform using 3 different functions.

As far as I am aware my functions are set up.

How would I go about rectifying these waveforms however?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
#define SIZE1 80
#define SIZE2 62
#define SIZE3 29
double findAverage(short array[], int size);
double findRMS(short array[], int size);
unsigned findZeroCrossings (short array[], int size);

int main()
{
    // array of values in cosine waveform //
    short cosine[SIZE1] = {
    32767, 32666, 32364, 31862, 31163, 30273, 29196, 27938, 26509, 24916,
    23170, 21280, 19260, 17121, 14876, 12539, 10126, 7649, 5126, 2571,
    0, -2571, -5126, -7649, -10126, -12539, -14876, -17121, -19260,     -21280,
    -23170, -24916, -26509, -27938, -29196, -30273, -31163, -31862, -32364, -32666,
    -32767, -32666, -32364, -31862, -31163, -30273, -29196, -27938, -26509, -24916,
    -23170, -21280, -19260, -17121, -14876, -12539, -10126, -7649, -5126, -2571,
    0, 2571, 5126, 7649, 10126, 12539, 14876, 17121, 19260, 21280,
    23170, 24916, 26509, 27938, 29196, 30273, 31163, 31862, 32364, 32666
    };
    // array of values in triangle waveform //
    short triangle[SIZE2] = {
    15500, 14500, 13500, 12500, 11500, 10500, 9500, 8500, 7500, 6500,
    5500, 4500, 3500, 2500, 1500, 500, -500, -1500, -2500, -3500,
    -4500, -5500, -6500, -7500, -8500, -9500, -10500, -11500, -12500, -13500,
    -14500, -15500, -14500, -13500, -12500, -11500, -10500, -9500, -8500, -7500,
    -6500, -5500, -4500, -3500, -2500, -1500, -500, 500, 1500, 2500,
    3500, 4500, 5500, 6500, 7500, 8500, 9500, 10500, 11500, 12500,
    13500, 14500
    };
    // array of values in sawtooth waveform //
    short sawtooth[SIZE3] = {
    -24000, -22000, -20000, -18000, -16000, -14000, -12000, -10000, -8000, -6000,
    -4000, -2000, 0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000, 14000,
    16000, 18000, 20000, 22000, 24000, 26000, 28000, 30000, 32000
    };

    // TODO
}

double findAverage(short array[], int size)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    double average;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    average = double(sum) / size;
    return average;
}

double findRMS(short array[], int size)
{
    int i;
    double sumsquared;
    double RMS;
    sumsquared = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sumsquared += array[i]*array[i];
    }
    RMS = sqrt((double(1)/size)*(sumsquared));
    return RMS;
}

unsigned findZeroCrossings(short array[], int size)
{
     int zeroCrossings = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i + 1 < size; i++) 
     {
         if ((array[i] >= 0) && (array[i + 1]) < 0)
             zeroCrossings++;
         if ((array[i] < 0) && (array[i + 1] >= 0))
             zeroCrossings++;
     }
     return zeroCrossings;
}
```

Comment: With the exception of `RMS`, does this have anything to do with C++? Perhaps it is a better candidates for the DSP stack exchange?

Comment: I must use c++ for this assignment. @Mikhail

Comment: FYI, with the exception of the unused include, your code is C not C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your rectifications is just to have the absolute values of the datapoints, then simply rewrite them.

Something like this:

```
void rectify(short *array, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        if(array[i] < 0)
            array[i] *= -1;
}
```

How to use it in this context. Put these at the end of the `main` function:

```
printf("Avg of sawtooth: %f\n", findAverage(sawtooth, SIZE3));
rectify(sawtooth, SIZE3); // Note: the sawtooth array changed.
printf("Avg of rectified sawtooth: %f\n", findAverage(sawtooth, SIZE3));
```

Comment: So is it better to use a function for the rectification part? @Koshinae

Comment: It depends on your needs :) This function replaces the values in-place. If you wish to keep the original, you'll need another array and copy all the values there.

Comment: So if I want to run my three functions through the new 'rectified array' how would I go about that? I'm a bit of a c++ beginner.. @Koshinae

Comment: This way, you call the `rectify` first, which will change the arrays you call it with in place. Then you simply call the three functions and their results will be based on the rectified arrays. I think `findZeroCrossings` will not produce any results on the rectified waveforms.

Comment: could you show me an example of the rectify call? I think this will help me out a lot! @Koshinae

Comment: rectify(cosine, SIZE1);

rectify(triangle, SIZE2);

rectify(sawtooth, SIZE3);

would this work? @Koshinae